# How to figure out optimal max_worker_processes?

Tags: postgresql

Yet I can not find any reliable recommendation regarding the optimal value for max_worker_processes.

Some sources suppose that the value should not be higher than the number of available cores, but is that correct taking that server threads do a lot of IO?

Say I have 8 cores for PG container and plan to handle about 100 clients in parallel. Is that feasible, especially with the default max_worker_processes=8 ?

Any trusted reference would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasonable limit dies not depend on the number of client connections, but on the actual upper limit on concurrent queries.

If it is guaranteed that only one of these clients will ever be active at the same time, you could set `max_worker_processes`, `max_parallel_workers` and `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` one less than the number of cores or parallel I/O operations that your storage can handle, whatever of the two is smaller. In essence, one query can then consume all the available resources.

On the other hand, if many of these clients are likely to run queries concurrently, you should disable parallel query by setting `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to 0 to avoid overloading your database.

Concerning your comments to my answer: if your goal is to limit the number of active queries, use a connection pool.

Comment: May I ask you to elaborate a bit the latter configuration? I consider that many clients (say up to 100) will try to run queries concurrently. Parallel queries are not needed indeed. Should I still keep max_worker_processes and max_parallel_workers not above the number of cores?

Comment: It does not matter to which values these parameters are set, as long as you keep `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` at 0. This will disable parallel query.

Comment: Say parallel queries are disabled. But the mentioned numbers still limit the number of queries that could be run in parallel by distinct clients, no? The goal is rather to maximize that number in my case.

Comment: No, that would be `max_connections`. See the addition to my answer.

Comment: But I guess max_connections only limits the number of alive connections, not the concurrently executed queries? For example, pooled connection could be alive and do nothing for a long time. Description given for max_parallel_workers sounds like it limits the number of clients actually having their queries running at the same point in time. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You are wrong. It only limits the number of parallel worker processes *in addition to* the backend processes for the connections. The maximum size of the connection pool is the limit for active queries, and if there is no connection pool, it is `max_connections`.